# getting Error while executing a simple form

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I am a beginner to C#. I just created a simple form for my project using Visual Studio 2010, by importing some pictures into it. After deleting some unwanted images from Resources file it is giving the error:

> "Error 7 Invalid Resx file. Could not find file
>   'C:\Users\HP1\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2010\Projects\test\test\Resources\331295-krishna-playing-flute.jpg'.

After that I can't able make any changes in my form. Even after If I am making any changes it is not reflecting while executing the program.

Answer (score 0):

in your project open your resx file in visual studio.it is xml file and easily readable. you need to remove those line which are causing this error (If these images are of no use) or place the given jpg file at the required location

Answer (score 0):

I can't look at your file, but maybe error is that file contains source on files that do not exist. Remove those sources.